# Why do we use media query if we have already bootstrap classes for creating responsive website

Tags: bootstrap-4

If we can create a responsive website with bootstrap-4 classes so why do we use media query for responsiveness?

Comment: Its a matter of choice. You can decide to or not to use media queries after using Bootstrap. You can decide to add your own custom media queries, as long as it will not conflict with Bootstrap's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, Bootstrap is just a CSS framework. It still uses media queries and is not an alternate technology solution that replaces media queries. Bootstrap has simply "pre-written" many of the necessary media queries and styles necessary for a responsive website.

That being said, sometimes you still need to write a media query when Bootstrap doesn't provide a ready-made solution for something you need to achieve.

In those cases, Bootstrap also provides [a collection of SCSS mixins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) that make media queries very easy.

Answer (score 0):

actually media query is older technology to handle responsiveness of website after that bootstrap framework came in the picture 
as bootstrap is already using optimized media query so there is no point in using media query differently as bootstrap is responsive